# Perforce command line

Tags: perforce

What is the command line syntax to check whether there is file in my changelists(checkout or not) in Perforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for?  Do you want to see the list of files in a changelist?  That's `p4 describe`.